# Improve Tag Wiki visibility on Questions by not hiding it

Tags: feature-request, design, tag-wiki

I often see tags misused. Some of that misuse would be reduced if the user had read the tag-wiki.

I personally do read tag-wikis, but while I write a question, they vanish too fast while I type the tags. So, I have to manually bring them up again if I'm unsure.

This would be easier if the tag-wiki stays visible for all tags I have already selected. It could encourage more people to actually read whats written there.

On my screen there is a whole lot of space left of the question window, we could use it to display the tag wikis.
[image: Example screenshot]

So, instead of hiding the tag description as soon as the cursor has left it, we would display it left of the question area, for all screens that have enough space for that.

Ideally we could then also highlight text, in the selected example "Java **(not to be confused with JavaScript)**", "JavaScript **(not to be confused with Java)**" and "**Don't use this tag for expressing the 'use' of something**". But that's for another question (which has already been asked, iirc). To make the misuse elements be more prominent.

Comment: +1 this could be useful. Though don't expect miracles. It's not likely that many bad taggers will read them, but it would help.